# Does quickfix store received messages somewhere?

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I know that quickfix stores outgoing messages to .body file, but I am curious does it store incoming messages somewhere (i.e. file) and what should be set up to get that functionality?

Best,
D

Answer (score 3):

If you use [FileLogFactory](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_file_log_factory.html), then all incoming messages will be logged into a file in your logs folder (that you set at *FileLogPath*).

Answer (score 2):

if you set `FileStorePath=\path\` quickfix will save a .messages.current file there with the messages in raw format in it

Comment: I set FileStorePath and on that path I find .body, .header, .seqnums and .session files

Comment: I meant to say that I don't find there .messages.current file.

Comment: that is odd; it works fine on my system (I just tested it). do you have FileLogPath set too?